# Stop an interval from another function in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React and I try to build a timer component. Now I have the start function working but I would also like to stop the timer by an onclick handler. The problem is that the start function uses an interval, but I don't know how to stop that interval from another function.

My JS code

```
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      times: [],
      timer: false,
      currentTimer: 0
    }

    this.startTimer = this.startTimer.bind(this);
    this.stopTimer = this.stopTimer.bind(this);

  }

  startTimer() {

    const start = Date.now();

    this.setState({ timer: true });

    var timer = setInterval(() => {

      let time = new Date() - start;

      this.setState({ currentTimer: Math.round(time / 1000)});


    }, 1000);

  }

  stopTimer() {

    this.setState({ timer: false });
    console.log('stopped');

    //Clear interval here

  }
```

I know that the `timer` variable is the identifier of that interval but how can I access it and then stop it? I have tried almost everything but nothing seems to work and I just don't know how I can fix that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To stop the timer, you need the timer id, So First job will be to store the id in such a way that it should be accessible in all the class methods. 
Second job will be use `clearInterval` to clear the timer (timer id will be required here).

One option is, Store the timer id in class instance.

Like this:

```
startTimer() {
    const start = Date.now();
    this.setState({ timer: true });
    // storing the id
    this.timerID = setInterval(() => {
        let time = new Date() - start;
        this.setState({ currentTimer: Math.round(time / 1000)});
    }, 1000);
}

stopTimer() {
    this.setState({ timer: false });
    clearInterval(this.timerID);
}
```

Working code:

```js
class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(){
     super();
     this.state = {currentTimer: ''}
     this.startTimer = this.startTimer.bind(this);
     this.stopTimer = this.stopTimer.bind(this);
  }
  
  startTimer() {
    const start = Date.now();
    this.timerID = setInterval(() => {
        let time = Math.random() * 10;
        this.setState({ currentTimer: time});
    }, 1000);
  }

  stopTimer() {
     clearInterval(this.timerID);
  }
  
  render(){
     return (
        <div>
          Value: {this.state.currentTimer || '0'}
          <br />
          <button onClick={this.startTimer}>Start timer</button>
          <button onClick={this.stopTimer}>Stop timer</button>
        </div>
     )
  }

}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app' />
```

Answer (score 2):

Save the timerId as a class instance variable which can then be accessed from other functions and used to clear the interval

```
constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      times: [],
      timer: false,
      currentTimer: 0
    }
    this.timer = null;

    this.startTimer = this.startTimer.bind(this);
    this.stopTimer = this.stopTimer.bind(this);

  }

  startTimer() {

    const start = Date.now();

    this.setState({ timer: true });

    this.timer = setInterval(() => {

      let time = new Date() - start;

      this.setState({ currentTimer: Math.round(time / 1000)});


    }, 1000);

  }

  stopTimer() {

    this.setState({ timer: false });
    console.log('stopped');

    //Clear interval here
    clearInterval(this.timer)
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `timer` variable is a local variable to `startTimer()` method, it stores the identifier of that interval but is not accessible outside the function scope.

To fix this, add following in `constructor()` method:

```
this.timer = null;
```

Then, in `startTimer()` method change:

```
var timer = setInterval(() => {

  let time = new Date() - start;

  this.setState({ currentTimer: Math.round(time / 1000)});


}, 1000);
```

to:

```
this.timer = setInterval(() => {

  let time = new Date() - start;

  this.setState({ currentTimer: Math.round(time / 1000)});


}, 1000);
```

Finally, add following in `stopTimer()` method:

```
//Clear interval here code here
clearInterval(this.timer);
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it`s the right approach, but if you look for a quick workaround, just make it global(outside Component). It works, soooo....)

Edit :
in Functional Components you have to use useRef()

link to ReactDOC: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-there-something-like-instance-variables

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31243984)